# Paste option is not allowed in Editext view android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am facing one strange issue in one of the adapter which contain two view holder one of image and one edit text. If initially i try to paste some copied text from some browser after long click it works perfectly but if add any image using file chooser to image view holder and try pasting it stops working. tried setting all the property for edittext such as

```
inputFeed.setSelected(true);
inputFeed.setTextIsSelectable(true);
inputFeed.setCursorVisible(true);
```

still it doesn't work can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Try to check what’s happened with `ClipboardManager` after you’ve added image. `ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) (getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)); cm.getPrimaryClip()...`

Comment: have u tried like this. in XML editext : `android:cursorVisible="true"` not programatically as urs.

Comment: Did you find any solution for above issue? I am facing the same.